# Как правильно: гавиалью или гавиалию?

Tags: выбор-слов

Речь о чём-либо, присущем гавиалу.

Comment: Можете быть уверены, что оба варианта равноправны :)

Comment: @grizzly, блин, ошибся. Исправил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шакал - шакалью, марал - марал**ью** (*Маралья шкура*, диал. "Маралина" - так в книгах, напр. Словарь русских говоров Сибири, Наука, Сибирское предприятие РАН, 2001, с. 259), *гавиал - **гавиалью***. Разве что как поэтическую вольность можно допустить альтернативу:

> Сытно ел и сладко пил, 
>  Посещал Италию. 
> Для сапог своих купил 
>   
> Шкуру гавиалию.